# Pointwise convergence of $ f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences, pointwise-convergence

I'm studying Real Analysis and I'm trying to solve the following problem

> **Problem:** Show that this sequence $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by
> $$
> f_n = \frac{(x+1)^{2n+1}+(x-1)^{2n+1}}{(x+1)^{2n+1}-(x-1)^{2n+1}}
> $$
> converges to a function $f$.

**I need some hint** to deal with that sequence. I've tried many kind of algebraic manipulation but none gave me a good expression to evaluated this limit when $n\mapsto \infty$ at different domains of $x$.

**My last idea** was wrrite $f_n$ as

$$ f_n (x) = \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1}}-\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{2n+1}}$$

But it simply turns into a mess at the moment to know which occours in different domains of $x$ because we have to deal with more than one inequality simultaniously.

Comment: If $|(x+1)/(x-1)|<1$ then $f_n$ converges to ... <br> If $|(x+1)/(x-1)|>1$ then $f_n$ converges to ... <br> If $|(x+1)/(x-1)|=1$ then ...

Comment: Thanks. Doing it I got that this sequence converges to $1$ for any $x$ such that $|(x+1)/(x-1)|\neq1$

Comment: If $ x=-1 $, it goes to $ -1$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah thanks for remember. Using the last expression we are not able to evaluate $x=\pm 1$. We need to use the original expression for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

If $ x= 1 $ then
$$f_n(1)=1\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(1)=1$$

for $ x\ne 1 $,

$$f_n(x)=1+\frac{2}{(1+\frac{2}{x-1})^{2n+1}-1}$$
So

$$x>1\implies 1+\frac{2}{x-1}>1$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=1$$

$$-1<1+\frac{2}{x-1}<1\iff$$
$$-1<\frac{1}{x-1}<0\iff$$
$$x-1<-1\iff x<0$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=-1$$

$$-1=1+\frac{2}{x-1}\implies x=0$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=0$$

finally

$$0<x<1\implies -1<x-1<0$$
$$\implies 1+\frac{2}{x-1}<-1$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=1$$

$$------------$$
The pointwise function limit $ f $ is defined by

$$f(x)=-1 \text{ if } x<0$$
$$f(0)=0$$
and
$$f(x)=1 \text{ if } x>0$$

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your manipulation gives a better (far more clear) way to analyse the convergence in differents domains of $x$.

Comment: @Syr You are Welcome .